# Add User to Specific folder in /public_html/

Tags: apache2, sftp, wordpress

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2 server with Apache2, hosting a large Wordpress multi-site network.

My co-workers occasionally need access to a single directory to make minor adjustments to files and folders therein:

`/var/www/public_html/wp-content/themes/` (which has chown of `myname:www-data`)

How can I make a user account like `team` to access **only** said folder via something secure like `sFTP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a group account, then you add each of those co-staff to that group.

1. Create group `team`:

   ```
   sudo groupadd team
   ```
2. Change group ownership of that folder:

   ```
   sudo chgrp -R team /var/www/public_html/wp-content/themes/
   ```
3. Set permissions on the folder:

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/public_html/wp-content/themes/
   ```
4. Now add them to team group by appending `team` group to the groups they already belong to:

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G team <team_membership_username>

   # For multiple member adds use:

   sudo gpasswd -M member1 member2 member3
   ```
5. If you need a special `password` for team:

   ```
   sudo gpasswd team
   ```

Information:

For the merits of group passwords please see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93123/typical-use-case-for-a-group-password). Not an expert but would suggest reading up on the merits of adding one before doing so. The permission of `775` could be `774` it's up to you.